# Evaluation of $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan (x+1)}{x^2+4} dx$ in closed form?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, trigonometric-integrals

I have used the substitution $u= x+1  $ then $du =dx$ to evaluate the following integral in closed form and since $\arctan$ is connected to $x^2+1$ as it is a derivative of it.
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan
(x+1)}{x^2+4} dx$$ 
But i didn't come up to it's closed form the [inverse symbolic calculator doesn't give](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.741221&lookup_type=simple) me the closed form for it , and all my attempts gives me this approach : $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan
(x+1)}{x^2+4} dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{3\pi}{8}\arctan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ But this is not the same result with [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(+arctan(x%2B1)%2F(x%C2%B2%2B4)),+x%3D1+to+infty), Any way ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a mistake somewhere since 
$$\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{3\pi}{8}\arctan \big(\frac{1}{2})=0.687479$$ while Wolfram Alpha returns a value equal to $0.741221$ which is correct.